# Upgrade existing Windows 2012 Datacenter to Windows 2012 Datacenter R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, datacenter

I am currently using Windows 2012 Datacenter and I would like to upgrade it to the Datacenter 2012 R2 version.  Is the upgrade free from Microsoft?  Or do I have to buy either an upgrade version or a R2 full version? Appreciate everyone's advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upgrade is not free. Please consult Microsoft for licensing advice.

Comment: I hope I will not end up paying the same purchase price for Windows 2012 Datacenter since I already have one.  Just the R2 is what I'm after.  Thanks much.

Comment: @GeePee this is exactly why you purchase Software Assurance with your licenses. People that don't buy
 SA are living in 2005.

Comment: @GeePee To add to what Mark said, Microsoft is planning on doing yearly OS releases (like Apple), so the this is only going to get worse - unless you buy SA.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by [MichelZ in his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/586615/118258), it's not a free upgrade.

In fact, [Microsoft upped the price of Server 2012 R2 by almost 30%, compared to Server 2012](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-ups-price-on-windows-server-2012-r2-datacenter-by-28-percent-7000019168/), and at least currently, the only option to ypgrade to Server 2012 R2 is with a Server 2012 R2 license.... which you'll have to shell out the full price for, unless you already purchased Software Assurance. Sorry.

> "Anyone who did not purchase Software Assurance on their previous server licensing (Windows Server) will need to purchase their server licenses all over again if they want to upgrade," said Aidan Finn, a Microsoft Valuable Professional (MVP) with an expertise in Virtual Machine who works for MicroWarehouse Ltd, an Irish Value Added Distributor, as a Technical Sales Lead.